# Downloading map from ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, orthophoto

I want to download orthoimagery from this link:

https://geolibrary-maine.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/595cf522a36b4c6593acc7a8d5db3190

But when i click download button, the result is;

[image]

How can i download high res ortho image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map service isn't designed to download the entire dataset in one go. It can probably be done with some scripting and the rest endpoint, https://gis2.maine.gov/arcgis/rest/services/megis/ortho2016ImgSvc/ImageServer/exportImage, but that isn't how the map service is designed to work. Either consume the service directly in your application or contact the administrator directly.